# awesomeprint in irb unrecognized

Tags: ruby, irb

If I `require ap`, irb returns true (I assume telling me that the awesomeprint gem has been successfully loaded). However if I issue the command `ap f` where `f` is a hash, I get:

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `ap' for main:Object
from (irb):5
from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Thoughts?

Here is my $LOAD_PATH:

`"/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/multi_json-1.1.0/lib", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/multi_xml-0.4.1/lib", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/httparty-0.8.1/lib", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ap-0.1.1/lib", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/psych-1.2.2/lib", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/crack-0.3.1/lib", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1", "/usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-darwin11.3.0"`

It seems ap is the 4th one.

Comment: What is the result of `defined?(AwesomePrint)`?

Comment: nil. That doesn't seem good. I made sure to try to reinstall it (`sudo gem install ap`) and it was successful

Comment: I think there is another ap.rb in your load path.

Comment: okay. How can I check that without going through my entire load path (which is very long). I added it to the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The gem you want is called awesome_print, so `sudo gem install awesome_print` should fix it.  May want to remove the other gem 'ap' which seems to be some http and xml related gem.

Comment: Ah damnit. Got the command `ap` confused with the gem itself. Thanks for the help!

Comment: doh.. made the exact same mistake!